# How to map multiple sub-domains to different hosts in nginx?

Tags: nginx, proxy, dns, reverse-proxy

I have n no. of sites:

```
myserver1.com:1000 , myserver1.com:1001, myserver2.com:1010.............
```

I want to map these sites to different sub-domains:

```
firstsite.example.com, secondsite.example.com, thirdsite.example.com ..........
```

How can I do that in nginx server? What are all the configurations that are required? As I'm new to server side, step-by-step explanation would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create following configurations for achieving it:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name firstsite.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://myserver1.com:1000;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name secondsite.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://myserver1.com:1001;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name thirdsite.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://myserver2.com:1010;
        }
}
```

---

**But, question arrises why you actually wish to do so ?**

Correct approach would be using different `A records` for each of your subdomains. Configure your site's A records as:

```
  ┌────────────┬─────────────────┼───────────┐
  │    NAME    │         IP      │    TTL    │
  ├────────────┼─────────────────┼───────────┤
  │ firstsite  │ IP of myserver1 │    ∙∙∙    │
  ├────────────┼─────────────────┼───────────┤
  │ secondsite │ IP of myserver1 │    ∙∙∙    │
  ├────────────┼─────────────────┼───────────┤
  │ thirdsite  │ IP of myserver2 │    ∙∙∙    │
  └────────────┴─────────────────┴───────────┴
```

Now create nginx configurations on each server only for those subdomains you wish to open through it.

Example of configurations you should do *ideally*:

```
# These below configuration on myserver1
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name firstsite.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1000;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name secondsite.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1001;
        }
}
```

---

```
# These below configration on myserver2
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name thirdsite.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1010;
        }
}
```

**REASON** 
Using the configurations I gave, everything would seem to be working, but at back-end your server's bandwidth would get exploited for no reason.